# Windows 10 Toast activation is forcibly terminating my program after a while

Tags: com, windows-10, toast

I am implementing Windows 10 Toast in C# Desktop (using this library as a wrapper: https://github.com/emoacht/DesktopToast/).

It all works as expected, except that when I respond to a Toast notification while my program is not running, it will start my program, but then forcibly terminate it after a period of time. I do NOT want it to be terminated!

I notice that Windows is running my program with the `-Embedding` command line, which I gather is due to some COM / OLE automation. I guess responding to Toast is built on invoking my app as a COM server, the question is, how do I stop it being terminated?

Comment: When an out-of-process server is started by COM, it must call CoRegisterClassObject quickly as possible to tell the world at runtime what COM objects it has (note this is different from registering classids the registry). I don't see that in that library. It should be called on the objects implementing INotificationActivationCallback for example. You have an example here: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/DesktopNotificationManager/DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.cs

Comment: @SimonMourier It uses a wrapping library that results in the same call (at least according to MS): https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/registrationservices.cs#L328.

This is called from here: https://github.com/emoacht/DesktopToast/blob/6f2871211764188a3e443c4bea60618e1e514ce5/DesktopToast/NotificationActivatorBase.cs#L49.

(Why does it claim markdown links work in comments? They clearly don't...)

Comment: You' re right, didn't see that one. And do you call that method (with success)? It seems demonstrated only in the WPF sample.

Comment: Yes it is called and returns without error. 
I have worked around this problem for now by simply detecting the `-Embedding` command line and re-running my program outside the control of the parent process, so it can't terminate it. But I would like to know what the expected behaviour is here.

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/CoAddRefServerProcess.html

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant that looks like the thing! I will try and get the library authors to add it.